# Python BeautifulSoup equivalent to lxml make_links_absolute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

So lxml has a very hand feature: make_links_absolute:

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(some_html_page)
doc.make_links_absolute(url_for_some_html_page)
```

and all the links in doc are absolute now. Is there an easy equivalent in BeautifulSoup or do I simply need to pass it through urlparse and normalize it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(some_html_page)
for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    url_data = urlparse(tag['href'])
    if url_data[0] == "":
        full_url = url_for_some_html_page + test_url
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with lxml, but normalization of URL is not so easy. Do you really want to normalize them or only make them absolute?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my answer to [What is a simple way to extract the list of URLs on a webpage using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139989/what-is-a-simple-way-to-extract-the-list-of-urls-on-a-webpage-using-python/4140102#4140102) I covered that incidentally as part of the extraction step; you could easily write a method to do it on the soup and not just extract it.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def make_links_absolute(soup, url):
    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        tag['href'] = urljoin(url, tag['href'])
```

(Python 2: `from urlparse import urljoin`.)

Comment: Won't that fail if a there is a <base href...> in the document?  See e.g. [HTML base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp), which is handled by lxml (http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)

Comment: Sure; you can take the `base` tag if you want and parse it and use `urljoin(url, base)` instead of `url`. For myself, I have scarcely ever seen it used on the web and I will never use the `base` tag (least ways, not for a number of years, though even then I dare say I'll have no use for it) because it doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: I think you mean `urljoin(base, tag['href'])`.  I hear that use of base is common in e.g. [typo3 sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914922/ie9-only-sometimes-ignores-base-href) and I've used it e.g. when archiving pages.    I hear that the [ie8 bugs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/bugs-in-the-ie8-lookahead-downloader.aspx) have been fixed - do you know differently?  At any rate, I just wanted to clarify what it takes to have a python method that works in general like the lxml one.

Comment: @nealmcb: no, I meant what I said. That way it continues working with or without `<base>`. (Think about it again; the base tag should be interpreted as relative to the page URL.) Concerning the IE8 bug, I hadn't heard of its being fixed; I only know of it because my Dad was trying to use `<base>` on local files and it was actively not working (not merely delaying it as that suggests); brief hunting suggests that may be a different issue. He had to scrap the use of the base tag for that reason.

Comment: Ahh - I see what you were intending.  But it wouldn't make sense to do that, since a base href must be absolute: *12.4 Path information: the BASE element - This attribute specifies an absolute URI that acts as the base URI for resolving relative URIs* from http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.3.1

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - Yeah, you're right, I'm wrong about the behaviour, though it's absolutely on-topic, as I'm working on a system that does URL canonicalization. Anyways, comment deleted.

Comment: Python 3 version: `from urllib.parse import urljoin` https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin