# IE9 only _sometimes_ ignores <base href>

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

We are developing a site which makes heavy use of `<base href>` (which is typical for TYPO3 sites). The site is developed in a sub directory and will later be relocated to the top directory so we can not easily remove `<base href>`.

Our client told us that sometimes when she browses the new pages she gets the page content without layout applied. We debugged this: It happens only in IE9. Looking at the logs we find that when the error happens, IE9 tries to load CSS, JS and all images consequently from the wrong location: relative to the current URL, not relative to the BASE HREF... Further inspection of the logs show us that IE8 users are also affected, including some dumb web spiders (no problem for us with the latter ones, who cares?).

We already know about IE8 speculative downloader / lookahead parser: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/bugs-in-the-ie8-lookahead-downloader.aspx

I'm sure we are NOT facing bugs described THERE: All page elements (including first header element) are loaded from the wrong location. This bug describe that only second and later elements from the page header are affected. We can prove this by watching the access logs when the problem occurs.

A simple reload fixes the issue, comparing the page source code with the bug occurring and without it occurring shows absolutely no difference. Only IE is affected, all other browsers are fine.

The `<base href>` tag is the first in the `<head>` tag. We tried every possible solution, nothing helped. Seems to be an IE bug.

Anyone else experiencing this and found a work around? We have several other sites using `<base href>` where we cannot reproduce such behavior in our test systems - so something is probably triggering or working around this bug. But I analyzed the logs of these sites and can see that some visitors using IE8 even there experience that bug.

As requested in the comments, here's an obfuscated example of my html head:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<base href="http://client.site/cms/" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- 
    This website is powered by TYPO3 - inspiring people to share!
    TYPO3 is a free open source Content Management Framework initially created by Kasper Skaarhoj and licensed under GNU/GPL.
    TYPO3 is copyright 1998-2011 of Kasper Skaarhoj. Extensions are copyright of their respective owners.
    Information and contribution at http://typo3.com/ and http://typo3.org/
-->

<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 4.5 CMS" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3temp/stylesheet_fad97d0aa7.css?1312295592" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileadmin/css/styles.css?1319535102" media="screen" title="Standardstyles" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileadmin/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?1310653643" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileadmin/js/jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css?1312810052" media="all" />

<script src="fileadmin/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js?1310979164" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="fileadmin/js/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js?1312460310" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="typo3temp/javascript_93553eae97.js?1312462864" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="fileadmin/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />    
  <script src="/tools/formmailer.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script><title>Some title for the page</title>

</head>
```

Comment: can you add a simple example which expose the problem?

Comment: You should remove the comment or put it after the base. Putting a bunch of content in front of the BASE increases the likelihood that it's not seen in the first lookahead thread. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/18/optimal-html-head-ordering-to-avoid-parser-restarts-redownloads-and-improve-performance.aspx

Comment: @Eric We moved it up by changing the TYPO3 master template and clearing all caches. The problem still persists. I changed the example to reflect this.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- If you say "increases the likelihood" then I consider it a bug. IE9 never tries to fetch the resources from the correct URL when the problem occurs. It just does it wrong sometimes and that's it for that page session. Only a reload corrects the problem. From our logs I can deduce that other sites working with <base href> also face this problem, though only at a fraction of the rate it hits this new site. PS: Non-determistic behavior is almost always a software bug. I don't want to play yahtzee with IE, I want it to act deterministic.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- We found that when the error occurs and we use the F12 debugging tools, IE interprets data coming from `head` as belonging into `body`. Exactly always when this happens, the `base href` is ignored.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- We found it! If you want to reproduce this behavior include BOM into the html output. During page generation one PHP file with BOM was included, it was not included upon successive requests which hit the cache. So sometimes it happended (first request), most times not (successive requests). Yeah thank you IE, 2 .5 days of work lost! \o/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We found it: Internet Explorer does all sorts of funny things when the HTML file returned from the server contains a UTF-8 BOM. We still consider this a IE bug but at least we found a work around.

Background info: During initial page generation some PHP files where included which are not included for successive requests (because most generated content is cached now and these files do not need to be run). Some of such included PHP files included a UTF-8 BOM. Because the BOM comes before the opening PHP tag, it is streamed out to the output of PHP.

We figured it out by comparing outputs in fiddler and the file sizes differed by 3, 6 or 9 bytes when the error occured. Running a diff over the outputs showed the BOM header, comparing in most Windows editors didn't show it because these editors know about a BOM. So the problem was hidden. Thank you IE for 2.5 days of useless work!

Comment: Can you explain further? I have my `<base>` tag properly working for everything except for `window.location.href` calls in JS on IE.

Comment: I cannot confirm this solution. My file has no BOM but <base href> is totally ignored on IE 9. But after removing the <!DOCTYPE html> the <base href> suddenly works correctly even with BOM. Even more weird: I display the Html document in an embedded IE control in my application. When I start my application in the VS debugger it works with the <DOCTYPE html>, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever run into such a problem again, consider removing the `base` tag with `config.baseURL >` and render all links with an absolute URL:

Either use `config.absRefPrefix = http://www.example.org/mysubfolder/` (most save variant) or use `config.absRefPrefix = /`.

Comment: Won't help, it was a different issue. It's only with IE and BOM... IE has problems with applying CSS styles when it encounters a BOM - not on every request, however. Actually, when we encountered the problem, we even tried your proposal without success. If you google for IE problems related to BOM and UTF-8 you will find many similar reports, totally unrelated to TYPO3.

Answer (score -1):

i suspect you're not using an absolute path in the  tag. IE is allowed to ignore your tag since its not specified correctly. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: I am using an absolute path in the base href. See my example. I've mentioned nowhere that this path would be relative.