# How to get absolute path for image on a website

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, relative-path, absolute-path

In Firefox it is possible to rightclick on image and select 'Copy image location'. This allows one to get absolute image path even if in image's src attribute only relative path is provided.
Is it possible to get this absolute path programmatically? Where it is stored?

I use Python3, requests to access the site, beautiful soup to parse html.

Comment: What is the page?

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139989/what-is-a-simple-way-to-extract-the-list-of-urls-on-a-webpage-using-python/4140102

Comment: There src attribute could be the full url, a relative path to the current page, a relative path to the domain or even moving up to a parents directory like  `src="../some_folder` and many other variations, there is no one way to magically get the full path with bs4, it is not a browser.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Unfortunately I may not give you page address to check, but again, in my case url + image src is not a solution. I suspected that bs4 can't deal with it, it only parses plain HTML. I was hoping that full path is stored somewhere, Firefox somehow can calculate it, and I want to be able to do same.

Comment: @wasd, your browser can run js and go up and down directories so that is the difference really, you may get closer to what you want using  something like selenium.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Solution

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'https://example.com/'
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# converting to a set will prevent duplicates
images = set([img['src'] for img in soup.find_all('img') if hasattr(img, 'src')])

for img in images:
    print(img)
```

## Extended Solution

In the case of images using a relative path (or external host, cdn, etc.) we can weed out the majority with the code below.

**Note:** This will not work when using local URIs (`file:///temp/web/img1.png`)

This code uses the `validators` package, so install with `pip install validators`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from os.path import join, normpath
import validators

url = 'https://example.com/'
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

images = set([img['src'] for img in soup.find_all('img') if hasattr(img, 'src')])

list_of_img_paths = []

for img in images:
    if not validators.url(url):  # If NOT a valid URL
        # Here we can assume we are dealing with a relative path
        formatted_url = normpath(join(url, img))  # format a valid url
        list_of_img_paths.append(formatted_url)  # add to list
    else:
        list_of_img_paths.append(img)
```

Comment: Neither simple nor extended solution is not actually an answer: Simple gives only relative path, while extended only **assumes** that full path is a url + image src, which sometimes (in my case for example) is not true.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `os.path.normpath()` to properly format relative paths that are above the current directory.

`"https://example.com/a/b/c.html"` and `"../../img.jpg"` joined becomes `"https://example.com/a/img.jpg"`